# TS2322: Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'undefined'. How to assign optional properties dynamically?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typechecking

I am trying to assign properties to an object to form a known interface called `ParsedArguments` and this is how it looks like:

```js
import {Rules} from "../Rules/types/Rules";

export interface ParsedArguments {
    //other props
    //...
    rules?: Rules,
}
```

And now in another function I am trying to form an object that reads values from `cli` and forms an objects complies to that interface. Something like this:

```js
private parseCliArgs(args: string[]): ParsedArguments {
        let res: ParsedArguments = {}

        for (const arg of args) {
            if (arg.startsWith('--')) {
                const {key, value} = this.getArgValues(arg)

                if (!res.rules) {
                    res.rules = {}
                }

                const rule: keyof Rules = key

                if (res.rules[rule]) {
                    //HERE I GET THE ERROR
                    //TS2322: Type 'STRING' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
                    res.rules[rule] = value
                }
            }
        }

        return res
    }
```

Even if I check if the property of `Rules` exists, it still gives me that error. I couldn't figure out yet and hope you guys help me on this. Here is how `Rules` look like:

```js
export interface Rules {
    someProp1?: boolean,
    someProp2?: number,
    //...
}
```

I also tried `const rule = key as keyof Rules` instead of `const rule: keyof Rules = key`, doesn't change anything.

I'd appreciate if you guys let me know if you guys need more clarification or I missed any parts. Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: What is `this.getArgValues`?

Comment: try commenting these lines and check... 
                if (!res.rules) {
                    res.rules = {}
                }

Comment: And define res as... let res: ParsedArguments = {} as ParsedArguments

Comment: @Balastrong it is something like this `getArgValues<T extends keyof Rules>(arg: string): { key: T, value: string }`

Comment: @DevLoverUmar then I get `TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.` error for `res.rules`

Comment: I'm not sure why you need that `keyof` though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK here is what I come up with. I used `built-in` Typescript generics which is quite useful in those case. Because in order to get those dynamic results, it is not quite wise to define different types all the time. You will end up cascade of types then. See below:

```js
let rules: Partial<Record<keyof Rules, string>> = {}

for (const arg of args) {
    if (arg.startsWith('--')) {
        const {key, value} = this.getArgValues(arg)

        if (this.isRuleKey(key)) {
            rules[key] = value
        }
    }
}
```

Now with this solution I don't have to create another version of `Rules` type. Everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have compatible types in `Rules` and `value`. In `Rules` you have optional `boolean` and `number` (so they implicitly includes `undefined`) and in `value` you always have `string`.
If you will make all props in `Rules` as strings then they will be compatible.

See [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoFcA2EDOyDeAsAFDJnI4D2AthAApSUAOAjAPwBcFYUoA5gBoS5CjXqMmAJk7deIQcPJVaDZgGYZOHvyGlyAen0A6EyQC%20JEqEixEKOnCg4IAEwCCUPulrg8RPWSGlGAAFtDITBI4ioHGpgHIUFi4XBjYOLoWxCQw6CAIYMCUIMh8EGAefABqcJjouAAUjnxcWnJ8AJRc%20MgA1hAAnlz9A5QwaMkZyAButfWt2vLIZgQxieXoUCU9ayIjXADkyuLMLAe6IiKzdRBczWtZWTl5BUUlTI7OAMKYwJU4TU8OAW7QA2gBdLrIBxOVyVbwQXyrBIiBDFLTrYHQz5wzwIpEAXmRlxJiUm3V2pJEx1UrEOcHOlKpZBpEkkhwARgcmZcslSzABuSwo8gwShQZANNEgDHNZBjZDNHAdYnMsjAcaAvhGLSOMA4ADqwFCDQOAFozQcOir-GqSdKMfgRgIZnMICsiWUKp4ajcAc0OsK7ZcNZKAIRQXBGJLpG084ORnDRybIIn4PnB8hPEVqh1gMnYYaDBVpXCpvqDIOZ9WaxPJ9KgmMQSGq6siQwACQAoqgu8gAJLIADiXYAKshR93kD3UAB5VDxu2GUcAZUkakk7InAyYKAOK9HqH7ADkhwdkMA8CBgoqcDhgHwQHAOdhkGBKG%20d3u8i4IDBQK4BxGIuap1k2OCNsk4Lltc9Qgby8EZiS2ZUpGYCbCUiYPEAA) to get a better view of what I mean

Comment: Thanks for your answer and this is something I thought of, which of course makes sense and if I apply to that I might solve the issue. I mean for example if I create `res` variable with default values in the `Rules` interfaces yeah I can manage to get it work. But my question is more like how can I assign optional properties dynamically ?

Comment: You see that TS typing is not a strong typing language and you don't have type information in runtime. It's all about describing a shape and not a strict type. So that said you cannot dynamically get type information at runtime. And on compiling time you need to define compatible types, i.e `someProp1?: number | string | boolean` and `value: string | number | boolean`

Comment: Well you are right but JS is very dynamic language and you gotta have some kind of dynamism.